Why does tension increases when we climb up a rope?
I am very confused in mechanics problems like a person is climbing a rope tied on ceiling of elevator, pulley or tree.
My confusion is why do we assume tension to be increased when we are climbing up the rope
I know, as person climbs up the rope, there must be some force propelling it up and there are just two forces acting on the person we are aware of

Tension upward
Weight downward

And then we conclude T - mg = ma.
But when the person was at rest, T = mg.
So from where does the extra tension force comes as we climb up the road or is it some other force that is propelling up and tension is still equal to weight?
We can also think it as,
when we are at rest holding the rope, the tension in rope balances our weight. Now when we start to climb up we just push our upper body upward release one hand and hold the upper part of rope and continue this. How in this process the tension increases as our weight remains constant and we are just changing body's pose?

This isn't the same question, but it might help. Why is the tension on both sides of an Atwood machine identical?


Why does tension increases when we climb up a rope?

It increases due to Newton's 2nd and 3rd laws. See the Figure below.
When we climb up a rope our muscles exert a downward force on it. Call that force $T$. See the free body diagram of the rope in the figure. Per Newton's 3rd law the rope exerts an equal and opposite upward force $T$ on us. See the free body diagram of the person in the figure. Then per Netwon's 2nd law we accelerate upward due to the net force upward on us.
Since the rope is attached to the support in the figure below, it cannot accelerate (we'll assume the rope is inextensible). Thus the force $T$ that we exert down on the rope equals the force $T$ the support exerts up on the rope. That is the tension in the rope. The harder we pull down on the rope the greater our upward acceleration and the greater the tension produced in the rope, since
$$T=m(a+g)$$
If we simply hung by the rope (i.e., $a=0$) the tension would equal our weight, $mg$.
Note the above assumes the mass of the rope is negligible compared to our mass. If not, you would simply need to add the weight of the rope to the tension (again assuming the rope is inextensible so that the tension is uniform all along the rope).
Hope this helps.


This helps but I just need to figure out why we need to pull the rope downward whole climbing

@YugAhuja You need to pull downward so that the rope will exert a force on you upward. Newton's third law dictates that. How else do you suppose you move upward?

ok but can you prove the converse. Why does tension reduces when we are going down a rope?

@YugAhuja Sure. But try it yourself,  assuming the person is accelerating down. Use the FBD of the person

@YugAhuja have you tried it?

Nope. But just done a thought experiment. Its like we are pushing the rope upwards but the rope is not going slack due to our weight. The tension should decrease when we push it upward but since the gravity is pulling us downward, the rope still have some tension. The total tension should be equal to sum of our push and our weight and since they are in opposite direction, the tension reduces. The acceleration in this case should be (mg-T)/a in this case I guess. I think it's just the additional push or pull we provide to rope that determines change in tension and our direction. So a = R/m.

R is the push or pull we give. If it is push then a is downward. If it is pull then a is upward. Am I correct? Also I want to ask, what if we provide it push greater than our weight?

@YugAhuja If instead of a rope you were climbing up a rigid rod, then pushing up would make sense as a rope cannot withstand pushing. You should think instead of loosening your grip to lower yourself which lowers the tension.  The greater the rate you lower yourself (the greater your acceleration downward), the lower the tension.

The effect is somewhere between the two extremes of simply holding on to the rope, where your acceleration is zero and the tension is $mg$ ,and completely letting go when your acceleration is $g$ and the tension is zero. But all of this can be seen from the FBD on the person.

For the person to accelerate downward, there needs to be a net force down acting on the person. That net force is $$ F_{net}=mg-T$$ The downward acceleration is then $$a=\frac{(mg-T)}{m}$$ That makes the tension as a function of the acceleration $$T=m(g-a)$$. When $a=0$, $T=mg$ (person just holding on) and when $a=g$, $T=0$, (person totally lets go), satisfying the two extremes.

That makes sense. Thank you very much

As you say, at rest you have that the tension force equals the gravitational force, but in opposite directions. We might write
$$T_1 = - m g,$$
or
$$|T_1| = |m g|.$$
Moving up the rope, the person pulls down on the rope, but the rope remains still, so they are propelled upwards. The positive acceleration $m a$ of the person is equal to a negative acceleration of the rope $- ma $, since the rope remains still. Thus, the tension must increase to
$$T_2 = - (m g + m a) > T_1,$$
or else the rope would start moving opposite the person.

But how does person adds the extra pull? As ast rest, he already pulls the rope. To climb the rope he just changes his body's pose but he does it by internal forces of his body. How does it contribute to extra force on rope in downward direction?

@YugAhuja, have you ever climbed a rope? You start with your hands above your head holding the rope. You contract your biceps and teres major(?), folding up your arms, and raising your center of mass relative to the rope. When you do it, you can feel in your hands that you are exerting a force on the rope.

@ThePhoton I know. But I am asking how we are exerting force on rope in this process. I know we feel it when we actually climb the rope but how by intuition in the transition from the state when our hands are above our head to when our centre of mass is raised, we exert force on rope? Shouldn't there be just internal forces playing on our body to change our pose of shape? and at the end just force of gravity is acting on our so tension should be equal to weight again after we finish the transition

@YugAhuja, suppose you are standing on the floor and you jump upwards. Do you understand why you have just exerted a force (greater than your weight) on the floor? There's no difference in the physics here. There is a difference in bio-mechanics, but I don't know enough about bio-mechanics to address that.

Hmm that's convincing enough, I guess. Thanks
